# Ubuntu Image hangs -- PI 4B with 4GB Ram 32G sd card hangs

Tags: raspberrypi

I am having the same issues. I have tried to flash the drive again, but it always prompts for login and then continues and hangs on the cloud init.

Is there a solution for this yet?

Pi 4B 4GiB ram

Comment: Welcome to [ubuntu.se]! Please [edit] your question to add details. What do you mean by “cloud init”? Could you add your actual output (at least some screenshots)?

Comment: You haven't said what OS/release you have tried?  Are you talking about Ubuntu 19.10?  Ubuntu 19.10.1? or something else? As currently provided, we can only guess as it's unclear; answers thus cannot be provided.   *Even beyond release, there are arm64, armhf..*

Comment: 19.10 is the only image that supports Raspberry Pi 4.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it's hung?  There is a bug where USB dies if you have 4gb of ram.  Try limiting it to 3gb and see if the problem persists...

You can try to connect using just SSH with 4gb and see if the system is functional.

Comment: Can you add some commands to follow?